# Can I click on a filename and line number in iterm2 to open that file in Visual Studio Code at the correct line number in OS X

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, iterm2

When Iterm2 shows a file name and line number in Mac OS X, can I ⌘-click on the file and have it open in an already open window in Visual Studio Code and position the cursor at the correct line number.

[image: Hold down ⌘ and hover to see the file and line number you are about to click]

(Asking this question to document the solution)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

It looks like you can just select "Open with editor..." in advanced settings > semantic history now

[image: iTerm 2 preferences pane]

Comment: haha, this answer is much better as this manages to handle different formats of writing the line and char numbers at the end of the filename. thx! typescript writes it using (123:45) .. which didnt work if you run the command specifically by writing code -r -g \1:\2

Comment: It should probably be mentioned, that it's Preferences -> **Profiles** -> Advanced settings, not just Preferences -> Advanced

Comment: If this is not working for you, my iTerm (v3.4.4, latest on catalina at time of writing) is interpreting "src/foo/bar.js" as a file url... when I cmd+hover I see a `file:///Users/<me>/repos/my-repo/src/foo/bar.js` in the bottom left.. iTerm then calls out to mac os to open this file.. I had to go to Finder>Right Click the buggy file/extension>Get Info>Change All.. and select VS Code. But you should still also set the "Open with editor..." setting, since it all works correct for `src/foo/bar.js:3:3` (key being the `:3:3` at the end).

Comment: I literally can't access gitlab.com on my work machine, but idk WHY iTerm would call out to OS when you have "Open with editor..." set. Also, the editor setting keeps getting reset back to Atom+grayed out.

Comment: Hey @SagivOfek, the answer you linked to suggests this as the more recent solution? Did you link to the wrong answer?

Comment: See also https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/10545

Comment: Please provide an equivalent iterm2 script which I can put in zshrc to enable this.

Comment: Erm, I don't think there's a way to programmatically set this @ArunGeorge, let me know if you find one. Related: https://iterm2.com/documentation-preferences-profiles-advanced.html

Comment: I had an issue where some files could not be opened in vscode - they would always open a new tab in Chrome instead. It turned out to be a problem in my test runner - it reported file paths relative to a directory other than the current directory, so the file paths did not point to existing files. It's pretty trivial but I figured it might be useful to someone.

Answer (score 39):

*UPDATE - see the newer accepted answer by @csilk for more recent solution*

It turns out you can, though it is not entirely obvious.

Go to Iterm2 Preferences > Profiles > (chosse the profile) > Advanced, then in the Semantic History section choose: Run Command, and enter the following:

`/usr/local/bin/code -g \1:\2`

[image: Iterm2 advanced profile settings]

If that appears to open in a new window then also try changing your Visual Studio Code settings by adding the following to your `settings.json`, press `⌘,` and add in the right hand pane add:

`"window.openFilesInNewWindow": false`

*EDIT* - as mentioned in the comments by @BenjaminPasero adding `-r` to the command line will also force the file to be opened in the last active Code window, e.g.:

`/usr/local/bin/code -r -g \1:\2`

Comment: You can use "-r" to force it to reuse the last active window.

Comment: ah good tip @BenjaminPasero - i'll add that to the answer, thanks

Comment: regarding `"window.openFilesInNewWindow": false`
it seems it should be `"window.openFilesInNewWindow": "on"`

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative solution you may still use the default configuration of iTerm2 (open files with default app) but adjust the default app for file itself in MacOS.

**File  -> Get Info -> Open with:** ->

and set your app in combobox (also changes may be applied to all type like the following one)

Answer (score 1):

I did not find the configuration in iTerm2 to set the default editor.
However, it turns out there is another solution.Check out the image below.
[image]
[set default app for *.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etLA7.png)

Comment: I don't think this will work with line numbers?

Answer (score 0):

As an update to @danmux's answer:

In newer versions of iTerm2, you can enable VS Code as the default editor to open filenames by opening `iTerm2 > Preferences > Profiles > Advanced > Semantic History` and then selecting "Open with editor..." and "VS Code" from the two drop downs.

[image: Open iTerm2 preferences > profiles > advanced > Semantic History]

PS: `.ts` files are historically video files, so that's why it's trying to open it with a media application.